# Math abs and ceil output compile error

Tags: java

I need help. I was trying to use Math class to do the calculation of some number. i can compile the code, but i never get the output. im using Jcreator compiler. anyone know what i did wrong with my code. thank you for your input
here is my code

```
public class Exercise607
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        double x=7.5;
        double xx;
        System.out.printf("the absolute value of x is %.2f\n", xx(x));
    }

    public static double xx( double x )
    {
        return Math.abs(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never mention if you run the code.  You mention that you're *compiling* it.  Running it, I'd see no issues.

Comment: im sorry, I compile it and it works. when I run the code i don't get the value. so i wonder if i did some thing wrong

Comment: Remember:  you execute your Java code with `java Exercise607`.  `javac` requires the `.java` extension, but `java` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your local `double xx` is never used. Also, your format `String` only includes one floating specifier. I think you wanted,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double x = -7.5;
    System.out.printf("the absolute value of %.2f is %.2f%n", x, xx(x));
}

public static double xx(double x) {
    return Math.abs(x);
}
```

Output is

```
the absolute value of -7.50 is 7.50
```

Comment: hmmm... i wonder why i don't get the value. this is what i get then i run the code

Comment: --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32   use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64   use a 64-bit data model if available
blablalbalba.....

                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.

Process completed.

Comment: Ummm... Have you compiled the java file to a class file? Is the the class file in your classpath? What is your precise build and run command line steps?

Comment: yes did. somehow i just don't get the output like yours. i even modify my code exactly like yours.

Comment: okay. the code works. I get the output when I run it with CMD command  windows. but when I try to run it with my Compiler Jcreator it just show me those lists of stuff... I thought I have a runtime error. thank you so much for helping me